# An sql statement to select the closest values

Tags: sql, sqlite

In the table below, that I'll call TableA are two numerical columns. I need to create a Select statement whereby the value of B is specified. Either one or two rows are returned. Not sure if this can be done in a single sql statement. If a row exists where the value of B matches, then just that row is returned. If the value of B is between two values of B that are closest to its value, both values are returned. If a value exists that is larger than it but no value exists that is smaller than it, than the larger value is returned. If no larger value exists but a smaller one does, than the row with the smaller value is returned. Here are some examples. It would be nice if the sql worked in sqlite:

```
A       B
50     400
10     200
30     100
40     800
20     500


B = 10

A       B
30    100

----------

B = 250

A       B
10     200
50     400

----------

B = 100

A       B
30     100

----------

B = 410

A       B
50     400
20     500

----------

B = 900

A      B
40    800
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE B = 10
UNION 
SELECT * FROM A WHERE B = (SELECT MAX(B) FROM A WHERE B < 10)
UNION
SELECT * FROM A WHERE B = (SELECT MIN(B) FROM A WHERE B > 10);
```

See it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/a5047/3).

Comment: P.S.: A minor tweak is to use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`. `UNION` implies a `DISTINCT` which is not necessary. On the other hand you just have max. 3 values, so there will be no measurable difference. Just mentioning it in case someone wonders :)

Comment: When searching for 200, this query returns three results.

Comment: So actually, it's 3 Select statements. I guess it isn't possible to have done it with just one Select statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE B = (SELECT MAX(B) FROM TableA WHERE B <= 10)
UNION
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE B = (SELECT MIN(B) FROM TableA WHERE B >= 10)
```